# How do I make my apps windows get their own Unity launchers?

Tags: unity, launcher, python, gtk, pygtk

I'm writing an application that potentially uses quite a few windows. It would be nice if I could make at least some of those windows get their own Unity launcher entries. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple .desktop files that launch the individual windows separately. You can either use `python filename.py` or write a wrapper script for the command line argument.

Comment: That would make the program much, much more complicated since it'd have its own process. I'm talking about dynamic windows of the same type. For instance, if you are a writer, then you might have the browser, nautilus, LibreOffice Writer and no other entries on the launcher. But it would be nice if you could switch directly between open documents, so you wanted each document to have its own launcher entry. In that case, making a desktop file for each document, is not feasible. Still, for each document to have an entry might be useful in some cases.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: that's completely unnecessary with the way Unity works. You click on an item with multiple windows to open scale mode and that shows you all the windows.

Comment: I am aware of that, but that does not provide any keyboard shortcuts directly to a specific window.